# what happens if you push to a deleted repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, repo

I deleted a bitbucket repo and tried to push a commit to it.

I get the following error

```
permission denied (publickey) 
fatal: could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

What actually happens when this error occurs.

1. Can it create a new repository?
2. Does it send the commit changes anywhere?

Comment: Do you see a new repository in your bitbucket account after running this command?

Comment: No, your push is just rejected, doesn't create anything.

Comment: @RomainValeri does it send the changes anywhere

Comment: 1: No it cannot. Use a bitbucket cli, or create it on their website. 2: No, they don't go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Can it create a new repository?

In theory BitBucket could decide that a failed attempt to push to an inexistent repository creates a new repository on their server. But I don't think they would actually do that.

> Does it send the commit changes anywhere?

No, it doesn't know where else it should send them to.

Comment: Is there any documentation that would say they don't create one on failed push. I'm struggling to find anything online

Comment: I think it's safe to assume they don't if it's not mentioned anywhere. https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-a-new-repository/

Comment: I don't know, but I can imagine that this isn't documented.

Comment: I hate making assumptions :(